# Random Point for Label

Tags: c#, random

I have an application where i need to populate data from a database onto 4 labels and I want these labels to appear at random position x but at the following location x : 79, 199, 437, 319.

I tried to use the `Random` class but it returns the same location occasionally. Anyone has a solution for this please? I want answer1 - answer 4 below to shuffle location each time the application is run.

```
answer1.Location = new Point(79, 60);
answer2.Location = new Point(199, 60);
answer4.Location = new Point(437, 60);
answer3.Location = new Point(319, 60);
```

Comment: I'd keep the position of the labels the same and only shuffle their association/meaning.

Comment: A clever user could always see the answer from a utility that shows the window order, like Spy++.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your points in a `List<Point>`:

```
var list = new List<Point>
    {
        new Point(79, 60),
        new Point(199, 60),
        new Point(319, 60),
        new Point(437, 60)
    };
```

Then, you shuffle it with the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

```
var rand = new Random();  
var n = list.Count - 1;  
for(var n = list.Count; n > 0; n--)
{
    int k = rng.Next(n - 1);  
    var value = list[k];  
    list[k] = list[n];  
    list[n] = value;  
}
```

And then you use:

```
answer1.Location = list[0];
answer2.Location = list[1];
answer3.Location = list[2];
answer4.Location = list[3];
```

Comment: @avi (+1 for this answer, but...) We should also mention that you must not keep creating a new `Random()` because if you create them too closely together in time, they will produce the same numbers (due to them using a relatively slowly changing timestamp as a seed). You should create a `Random` once in your Form class and re-use it for each shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

I thing your usage is false.

the Correct usage of the [Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.random.aspx) is :

1. Instantiate the class

   ```
   Random rnd1 = new Random();
   ```
2. Than access the "randome" function to get a randome number with:

   ```
   var yourrand = Random.Next(437 /*The maximum*/);
   ```

[Next function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/zd1bc8e5.aspx)